# Empty NFC tag opens application... even if it's already open. How can I stop this?

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

I have an application that reads NFC tags. It reads them just fine--meaning the open application reads the tags without opening the application again--unless the NFC tag is empty. In this case, the NFC tag opens the application, which is already open. Then we have two of the same application.

My goal would be to connect to the empty NFC tag and enable the currently open application to write to it.

A snippet from AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
```

Enable foreground dispatch method:

```
    private fun enableForegroundDispatch(activity: AppCompatActivity, adapter: NfcAdapter?) {
    val intent = Intent(activity.applicationContext, activity.javaClass)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity.applicationContext, 0, intent, 0)

    val filters = arrayOfNulls<IntentFilter>(1)
    val techList = arrayOf<Array<String>>()
    filters[0] = IntentFilter()
    with(filters[0]) {
        this?.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED)
        this?.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED)
        this?.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
        try {
            this?.addDataType("*/*")
        } catch (ex: IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Check your MIME type")
        }
    }

    adapter?.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, filters, techList)
}
```

My nfc_tech_filter.xml lists everything!

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
</tech-list>
```

What the heck am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you are defining a tech list in the Manifest you would also have a filter for that.

Try changing you manifest snippet to be

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
```

But I think really problem is that it seems your `techlist` is empty (and because you are not filtering for `TAG_DISCOVERED` as well), as a fallback it reverts to Intent dispatch system which will try to launch another instance based on manifest.

From [1b](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc#foreground-dispatch)

> If it does not match, the foreground dispatch system falls back to the intent dispatch system

So try also changing `val techList = arrayOf<Array<String>>()`

to

```kotlin
val techList = arrayOf(arrayOf<String>(NfcA::class.java.name,
                                       NfcB::class.java.name,
                                       NfcF::class.java.name,
                                       NfcV::class.java.name,
                                       Ndef::class.java.name,
                                       NdefFormatable::class.java.name,
                                       MifareClassic::class.java.name,
                                       MifareUltralight::class.java.name,
                                       IsoDep::class.java.name
))
```

Hopefully this is right in Kotlin and I've not used `enableForegroundDispatch` for some time because of various issues with it, instead I use the much better API `enableReaderMode` to replace `enableForegroundDispatch`

Comment: I just wanted to follow up--using enableReaderMode fixed everything. Why on earth does the NFC documentation even refer to enableForegroundDispatch anymore? It is buggy, rigid, and unreliable. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @James just laziness on Googles part in not going back to up date the "guide" documentation once the new API has had a chance to bed in and be around enough to support most phones currently in use. It does not help that a lot of other guide on the internet still use `enableForegroundDispatch` still as well